# Understanding Soft Thresholding Operator

Tags: compressive-sensing, convex-optimization

I want to understand what is soft thresholding operator? Why we use this operator? I came across this term while I was reading the paper - [A New Algorithm Based on Linearized Bregman Iteration with Generalized Inverse for Compressed Sensing](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00034-013-9714-0#page-1) (at page no 4.).

Any reference that can explain this will also help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can't access that paper, but soft thresholding is used to induce sparsity; a solution with a small $L_0$ norm (number of nonzero elements). [It turns out that $L_1$ regularization helps achieve this goal](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45643/why-l1-norm-for-sparse-models).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The soft-thresholding function finds the minimizer of an objective function  that involves data fitting in an $\ell_2$ sense as well as minimization of the $\ell_1$ norm (i.e. absolute value). The [Lecture Notes - Penalty and Shrinkage Functions for Sparse Signal Processing](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/lecture_notes/sparse_penalties/sparse_penalties.pdf) gives a good discussion of how the soft threshold function is derived.

Comment: Please use the names of the resources you link to and not something like `this`. One day the link won't be available, but the name is always searchable.